# how to realize data exchange between father dialog and child dialog in wxwidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

If i want to the parent dialog get the data of the child dialog when a button（typically a OK button） of the child dialog's  button is clicked. how to realize?

My app is like this type: initialize i start an dialog, when hit the new button, it create a new dialog for configure a database connection. when input the necessary info. i can click the OK button of the child dialog, the child dialog will not live, then i need use the father dialog to save the info input in the child dialog.

How to realize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ `wxDialog` object remains alive even after the dialog on screen is closed. So typically you store the data in this object fields (either using [validators](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_validator.html) or by manually overriding `TransferDataFromWindow()`) and then retrieve it from this object as needed in the code that showed the dialog.